# Most concise way to use jQuery grep() to find match?

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to improve the elegance of this function:

```
  function findById(id) {
    var items = [
      { Id: 1, Value: 'My value 1' },
      { Id: 2, Value: 'My value 2' }
     ];

    var result = $.grep(items, function (obj) { return obj.Id === id; });

    return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : null;
  }
```

In particular, I'd rather it looked something like this:

```
  function findById(id) {
    var items = [
      { Id: 1, Value: 'My value 1' },
      { Id: 2, Value: 'My value 2' }
     ];

    return $.grep(items, function (obj) { return obj.Id === id; })[0] || null;
  }
```

That is obviously a big pile of fail, but the idea is that perhaps there is a cleaner way of writing the function. Not a big deal but I thought I'd write this up in case I am missing something.

[Edit] As pointed out, the ideal code works just fine. I had incorrectly assumed accessing the first element of an empty array would throw an error, but instead it returns undefined. Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work fine. Where should the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'ideal' code works fine. In C# this functionality is called `FirstOrDefault`.

This is currently not built into JavaScript (or jQuery afaik) however [it will likely be added](https://github.com/Ralt/or/issues/1#issuecomment-14940411) in the next version.

Our good friend Florian wrote a small function that would let you use the syntax you desire called [`or`](https://github.com/Ralt/or/blob/master/lib/or.js).

Here it is:

```
function or(arr, callback, context) {
    var el;
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        el = arr[i];
        if (callback.call(context, el, i, arr)) {
            return el;
        }
    }
    return null;//to return null and not undefined
}
```

Example:

```
or([1,2,3],function(elem){ return i>2;}); //returns 3;
or([1,2,3],function(elem){ return i>3;}); //returns null;
or([1,2,3],function(elem){ return i>1;}); //returns 2;
```

In your example, that would be

```
return or(items, function (obj) { return obj.Id === id; });
```

An advantage is it won't iterate through the entire array if it finds a match in the middle of it. If your arrays are big, that's a big difference.